# Eclipse Neon: Cannot Find Existing Project

Tags: eclipse

I am trying to find and open an already existed project (PyDev) in Eclipse but when I rebooted my computer and reopened Eclipse, my main screen was blanking and I was not able to find the directory tree, which is usually on the left view (as shown in the picture) 
[image] 
I already tried  **Project > Open Project** but it was greyed out. I also tried **File -> Import -> General -> Existing Projects into Workspace** to have your project in Eclipse as 
a few have recommended, but when I selected the root directory that contained the projects I previously created with Eclipse, I got a message that said "Some projects cannot be imported because they already exist in the workspace".
[image] 
[image]

Could somebody please show me how can I navigate back to the window where I can view my projects and start working on my projects? I was also wondering if there is any new control that hides projects from view?

Many Thanks!

Comment: Does _Window > Perspective > Reset Perspective..._ fix your issue?

Comment: Thanks for helping! Actually the Project explorer (left panel) & the projects did showed up but the modules/packages didn't. Looks like the project files are empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope below solution will work for you :

**Solution 1:**

Generally, eclipse is looking for eclipse-specific file in root directory like `.project`  and `.classpath`, that is missing in your scenario, try to create new work-space and switch there, and then try to import projects.

**Solution 2:**

1. Close Eclipse.
2. go to workspace.metadata.plugins
3. remove org.eclipse.core.resources
4. Start Eclipse
5. go to File->Import
6. General->Existing Projects into Workspace and import all the project from the workspace.

Note :- If the **Solution 1** was not enough, then try **Solution 2**.

If Project explorer  (left panel) is not  appearing, then you can Reset perspective from windows menu.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Solution 2 works perfectly. I got my projects and modules files back, and **Windows -> Perspective** does make the left panel show up again. Thank you very much!